# How use waits in Html Elements framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, wait, htmlelements

I have tried to use Html Elements framework. Here are one of my blocks:

```
@Block(@FindBy(id = "test"))
public class FirstBlock extends HtmlElement {

@FindBy(id = "nameS")
private TextInput id;

@FindBy(id = "saveBt")
private Button add;

public void addNewClient(String idText) {
    add.click();
    id.sendKeys(idText);
}
```

}

I have initialized page factory like:

```
PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(driver), this);
```

Now I want to wait after `add.click();` until next element is present.
As I found out where is possibility to use `AjaxElementLocatorFactory`
But how can I make this using Html Elements framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlElements use AjaxElementLocatorFactory by default, so you don't need any explicit waits in your code. It will try to find your `id` element until succeed and then executes `sendKeys()` on it. In case element wait timeout will be reached, it'll throw `ElementNotFound` exception.

Comment: Is where possibility to change timeout? Where I could do this?

Comment: yep, since [version 1.14](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/releases/tag/htmlelements-1.14) there is `@Timeout` annotation where you can set timeout for specific element, or setup `webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait` property which used as default timeout.

Comment: and you don't need `@Block` annotation since version 1.13